# How do I handle ZIP file entries with accents in their name?

Tags: java, file-io, zip

I have a simple filesystem copy routine that gets into trouble with ZIP-based filesystems. My code is relatively generic in that it does not specifically refer to ZIP classes, ie. it uses `FileSystem`, `Files.walkFileTree()` and `Files.copy()`.

Most of the time, my code works as intended, ie. a ZIP file in safely copied (unzipped) into a destination directory. It breaks when one of the ZIP entries has *unusual* characters in the name. I don't have a precise definition of *unusual* but it would appear that it's characters with accents, eg. `é`.

Here's the essential part of my code. `copyFileSystem()` *walks* through the file system and copies each file one-by-one using a `FileCopyVisitor`. (I do it this way so I can report progress on the overall copy - this code is not shown.)

```
public static boolean copyFileSystem(File src, File dest)
{
    boolean success = false;
    try (FileSystem fs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(src.toPath(), null))
    {
        Path root = fs.getPath("/");
        Files.walkFileTree(root, new FileCopyVisitor(dest));
        success = true;
    }
    catch (IOException | RuntimeException e)
    {
        LOG.error("Error copying file system", e);
    }
    return success;
}

class FileCopyVisitor implements FileVisitor<Path>
{
    public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path src, BasicFileAttributes attrs)
        throws IOException
    {
        File dest = new File(destinationDirectory, src.toString()); // <<==== error is here
        Files.copy(src, dest.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }
}
```

The issue is the call to `src.toString()` in `visitFile()` to find the name of the file to copy. When the `FileSystem` is a `ZipFileSystem`, then `src` is a `ZipPath`. The call to `toString()` fails with an `IllegalArgumentException` with the (frustratingly brief) message `MALFORMED[1]` when the filename contains accents. (I use a `Path` instead of a `File` as `src.toFile()` is not supported when `src` is a `ZipPath`.)

I attempted to work around this by avoiding the call to `toString()` altogether, thus:

```
Path dest = destinationDirectory.toPath().resolve(src);
```

However this results in a `ProviderMismatchException` presumably because the destination directory is a Windows filesystem, while `src` belongs to a `ZipFileSystem`.

I did manage to hack my way around this issue using reflection. That is, if `src.toString()` throws an exception, then I check to see if `src` is a `ZipPath` and, if so, use reflection to access its private `path` field which holds the filename. I think we can all agree this is A Bad Thing<sup>TM</sup>.

Does anyone have suggestions on a better way to handle this?

Comment: I tried on my computer and did not find any problem. Try running `javac` with `-encoding "UTF-8"` and `java` with `-Dfile.encoding=UTF8` and see if that works.

Comment: @Dabiuteef Thanks for the tip - unfortunately this didn't solve the issue for me. I was already encoding during compile. I added `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` to the VM arguments for my unit test just to be sure, but to no avail.

Comment: That was interesting. Maybe your zip file is not using utf-8, but some Windows codepage?

Comment: Possibly, how would I tell?

Comment: I don't know. Maybe you can ask another question for that.